# how provide a reference to a class which is not present in windows jre but present in mac jre

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, e4

i have developed a e4 application which runs both in mac os x and windows

i am using some classes which are present in the mac os x jre but they are missing in the windows jre

the missing file is showing error when we run it from windows eclipse

the same file is present in mac jre so this don't show the error when we run it from mac eclipse

referencing library is - /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/ui.jar (which is not present in windows jre)

i want get rid of the error in windows platform "eclipse"

if i add the ui.jar library as reference the functionality in mac goes crazy and throws runtime exceptions (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unimplemented)

Comment: It looks like you made a direct reference to a platform-specific jar. I believe that specific jar is used to make Swing look more 'Mac Native', and so of course wouldn't be on the Windows JRE.

Comment: how to refer  ,  other than a direct reference ?
any suggestions for this case ?

Comment: It would help if you posted some code showing where/how you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to state that this is a highly discouraged thing to do; Eclipse applications (and Java applications in general) are intended to be platform agnostic; introducing code that depends on platform-specific implementation is usually a **bad idea and last resort**. If you can come up with *any* alternative, I encourage you to do so.

Having said that...

You can isolate the code that uses the Mac-specific classes and place that into a Fragment. The Fragment would have constraints in it's manifest that allow it to only be installed on OS X. This is how SWT handles the platform-specific portions of its implementation.

Read more about Fragments [in the Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/fragment.htm&resultof=%22fragment%22%20).

Answer (score 1):

Put the Mac code in a plugin or fragment with the platform filter set in the MANIFEST.MF so that it is only included in the Mac build. For example:

```
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=cocoa) (osgi.os=macosx) (osgi.arch=x86_64) )
```

Specifies that the code is only for 64 bit Mac OS X.

You will have to arrange to call the code in the plugin only on the Mac. One way is to also have a Windows only plugin with Windows versions of the same classes.